# Use Bigquery API or bq command line tool to create new table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to come up with a programmatic way to generate a new bigquery table from a pre-existing table.  I know how to do this to create a new view using the bq command line tool

bq --project_id='myProject' mk --view="SELECT * FROM [MYDATASET.database]" myProject.newTable

But that creates a view and that doesn't help me, I need to create a table for a bunch of reasons.

I would be happy to create a view and then be able to generate a new table from that view periodically, but I can't figure out how to do that without doing it manually though the bigquery web interface.

I'd appreciate any help.

Brad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a normal table (not a view), you can use the copy command:

```
bq cp <source> <destination>
```

If you're trying to materialize a view, or if you need to modify the contents of the table in the process (e.g., adding/removing/transforming fields), you can run a query with a destination table:

```
bq query \
  --destination_table=<destination> \
  --allow_large_results \
  --noflatten_results \
  'SELECT ... FROM <source>'
```

The query option is more powerful, but you'll get charged for running the query. The copy is free.

Comment: When I try to use the bq cp <source> <destination> and the <source> is a view, I get the error

"Using table DATASET:dataBase.tablename is not allowed for this
operation because of its type. Try using a different table that is of type
TABLE."

I'm trying the other option out, but the query is complicated and takes quite a while to process.

Comment: bq cp won't work if the source table is a view. So you'll need to use the query version.